# jplayer bug for iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, jplayer

I am using the last version of the http://jplayer.org/ on my site and have problems with loading it on iphone from thread.

Page is super simple.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.jplayer.js" ></script>
<title>Test iphone</title>
</head>
<body>
Test
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer();
    });

    function SuperSimple() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("clearMedia");
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { artist: "Queen", mp3: "/test/examples/blue.monday/music/Innuendo.mp3", title: "Innuendo" });
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
    }
    function SuperSimpleWithDelay() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("clearMedia");
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { artist: "Queen", mp3: "/test/examples/blue.monday/music/Innuendo.mp3", title: "Innuendo" });
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
        }, 5000);
    }

</script>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1"></div>
<br>
    <button onclick="SuperSimple()"> SuperSimple </button><br><br>
    <button onclick="SuperSimpleWithDelay()"> SuperSimple with delay </button><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Like you can see there are 2 buttons. Both of them do the same simple thing - load media and play it, but 2nd function use the dalay function. It works everywhere but no on iphone.

I have have tried that page http://m.musiclib.org/test/examples/blue.monday/iphone.html on few devices

1. Iphone with ios 7.1.2 - doesnt work!
2. nokia lumia 720 - works!
3. Lenovo Vibe Shot with Andrioid 5.1 - doesnt work!
4. pc chrome / firefox / IE - works!

So my question is why is that? Actually for me looks like it stop working for iphone if I try run player from not main thread.Because it stop working everytime when I try run player after some delay, for example after ajax request.

Any help here? Can I fix it somehow?

Duke

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

instead of document

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```